# Windows Azure Mobiles Services scheduler execution timeout

Tags: node.js, azure, scheduler, azure-mobile-services

I am using a Mobile Services in Windows Azure. I use the new Scheduler available for a Mobile Service. The Scheduler I called SendOut.

I am running a pretty simple script that will insert a message to a queue. The entire script:

```
function SendOut() {
    var azure = require('azure');
    var queueService = azure.createQueueService("mailsoutscheduler", "[The key to the storage]");
    queueService.createQueueIfNotExists("mailsout", function(error){ });
    queueService.createMessage("mailsout", "SendOut", function(error){});
}
```

It works fine when I try to run the script once. It it scheduled to run every 5 minutes. And it usually goes fine. However sometimes I receive this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred. Error: One of your scripts caused the
>   service to become unresponsive and the service was restarted. This is
>   commonly caused by a script executing an infinite loop or a long,
>   blocking operation. The service was restarted after the script
>   continuously executed for longer than 1000 milliseconds.
>       at EventEmitter. (C:\DWASFiles\Sites\VogSendOut\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\runtime\server.js:84:17)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:88:20)

I cannot figure out why I get this error - or how to solve it.

Could it be because it's running in the FREE Mobile Service Tier?

Comment: I am also seeing this issue. I have seen other reports of this in the last 10 days or so. Perhaps this was a recently-introduced problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's due to the FREE mobile subscription.

try to add a 
try{}
catch{} block

and use console.log() to log if an error occured. It could help you to resolve you problem.

Comment: I already added some logging and have now extended it to a full try-catch block. It seems this where I get the error: var azure = require('azure');

Comment: I added a try-catch block around the function. I still get the unhandled exception as described in the initial question. So the try-catch block does not catch the error as I see no entries in my log (I print out the errors to the log). So it still seems like it is the require('azure'); that gives the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: one suggestion, are you sure this error is throw by this particular script? I've already faced this similar error but I've suspected the wrong script... So my suggestion is the following : create a new mobile service with only this script in the scheduler, nothing else. and wait to see if the error continue. If not, you've to check all your script to be sure you catch any error, else block or catch and that you always send a response to a request

Comment: It is thrown by the particular script because this is already the only script in the scheduler for the mobile service. I am already have a try-catch block around the entire script. So I find it kind of strange I do not catch the exception